# A possible bug in PDB module of Biopython (getting wrong coordinates for one of the residues)

Tags: bioinformatics, biopython

I beilive that I have found a possible bug within the PDB module of `Biopython`. In short, I have been looking at ligands within the 2r09 structure from PDB. This structure contains two copies of identical "4IP" hetero residues, which are both located closely to the protein molecules. You can see it very clearly here: https://www.rcsb.org/3d-view/2R09.

However, during the parsing process something strange happens, and the coordinates of one of 4IP residues change dramatically, so that it is no longer where it should be. In fact, it turns out noticeably shifted from its original position. I have manually compared the coordinates from within the pdb file and the ones I got using the biopython, and indeed they do not match. Moreover, when I save the opened structure from within the biopython without any additional manipulations done to it, I get wrong results, which I confirmed by visualizing two pdb files before and after opening and saving the structure with byopython.

By the way, the same can be done by using the `nglview` library for example, which lets you visualize structure inside the jupyter notebook. Once again, if the structure is loaded separately (not with biopython), it looks perfectly fine, which cannot be said about the structure loaded with biopython.

Here are the original coordinates (in **bold**) for the first 4 atoms of the 4IP residues for the original pdb files:

HETATM 5636  C1  4IP A 405      **80.967  85.113  26.680**  1.00 22.42           C
HETATM 5637  O1  4IP A 405      **82.327  85.039  27.129**  1.00 23.40           O
HETATM 5638  C2  4IP A 405      **80.917  85.791  25.309**  1.00 22.60           C
HETATM 5639  O2  4IP A 405      **81.463  87.121  25.385**  1.00 20.92           O

Here is what I get after saving the structure with biopython:

HETATM    1  C1  4IP A 405      **30.570  61.217 -13.415**  1.00 22.42           C
HETATM    2  O1  4IP A 405      **29.672  60.422 -14.201**  1.00 23.40           O
HETATM    3  C2  4IP A 405      **30.182  61.120 -11.938**  1.00 22.60           C
HETATM    4  O2  4IP A 405      **28.836  61.592 -11.740**  1.00 20.92           O

It is highly possible that I just did something wrong here, but I can't find what exactly.

Comment: You may get some ideas of what is going on by looking at the [issues currently reported in regards to the PDB module](https://github.com/biopython/biopython/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+pdb). Also check you are using the current version and note version (whichever you are using) here and anywhere else you post about your issue. If that doesn't help, ideally in your post here you'd show a minimal code to reproduce some of this.

Comment: cannot find 2nd copy of 4PI ?

Comment: does the parser gives you any warnings ? Set it to parser = PDB.PDBParser(PERMISSIVE=1, QUIET=0) to see any warning that is skipped

Comment: try  PDBIO.save(self, file, select=<Select all>, write_end=True, preserve_atom_numbering=False) with preserve_atom_numbering=TRUE

Comment: @Wayne Thank for the reply! I have checked the github page and haven't found my problem there. Also, I am using the 1.78 version of biopython, which comes with the miniconda installation.

Answer (score 0):

OK, working in Biopython 1,79,  I tried to load your pdb : [2r09](https://www.rcsb.org/structure/2r09) ,

borrowing from https://github.com/agpe/biopython-ligands

`active_site.py`, modified into :

```
import Bio.PDB
import numpy
from Bio.PDB import PDBIO

cnt = 0

def residue_dist_to_ligand(protein_residue, ligand_residue) :
    #Returns distance from the protein C-alpha to the closest ligand atom
    dist = []
    for atom in ligand_residue :
        if "CA" in protein_residue:
            vector  = protein_residue["CA"].coord - atom.coord
            dist.append(numpy.sqrt(numpy.sum(vector * vector)))
            return min(dist)

def get_ligand_by_name(residue_name, model):
    #Extract ligands from all chains in a model by its name
    global ligands
    ligands = {}
    chains = model.child_dict
    for c in chains:
        ligands[c] = []
        for protein_res in chains[c].child_list:
            if protein_res.resname == residue_name:
                ligands[c].append(protein_res)
                
    print('ligands:', ligands)            
    return ligands

def get_ligand_by_chain(chain_name, model):
    #Extract all ligand residues from given chain name
    global ligands
    ligands = {}    
    ligands[chain_name] = []
    chains = model.child_dict
    for protein_res in chains[chain_name].child_list:
        ligands[chain_name].append(protein_res)
    return ligands

def active_site(ligands, distance, model):
    # Prints out residues located at a given distance from ligand
    chains = model.child_dict
    for group in ligands.values():
        for ligand_res in group:
            print("ligand residue: "+ligand_res.resname, ligand_res.id[1])
            for c in chains:
                for protein_res in chains[c].child_list:
                    if protein_res not in group:
                        dist = residue_dist_to_ligand(protein_res, ligand_res)
                        if dist and dist < distance :
                            print(protein_res.resname, protein_res.id[1], dist)


def save_ligand(structure, filename):
    
    print('ligands.items() : ', ligands.items())
    
    
    otto = [x[0].id[0] for x in ligands.values()]
    
    print([x[0].id[0] for x in ligands.values()])
    
    nove= [x[0] for x in ligands.keys()]
    
    print([x[0] for x in ligands.keys()])
    
    # Saves ligand to a filename.pdb
    Select = Bio.PDB.Select
    
    class LigandSelect(Select):
        

        def accept_residue(self, residue):
               
            
                if str(residue.id[0]) in otto and str(residue.get_parent().id) in nove:
                    
                    global cnt 
                    cnt += 1
                    print('ligands ñ#'+str(cnt)+'  : ', str(residue.id[0]) ,' from chin : ', str(residue.get_parent().id))
                    
                    return 1
                
                else:
                    
                    return 0
    
    io=PDBIO()
    io.set_structure(structure)
    io.save(filename+'.pdb', LigandSelect() ,  preserve_atom_numbering=False)
```

after more googling realized that `def save_ligand(structure, filename)` could be written in a shorter way:

```
def save_ligand(structure, filename):
    # Saves ligand to a filename.pdb
    Select = Bio.PDB.Select
    class LigandSelect(Select):

        def accept_residue(self, residue):
                
            return residue  in [item for sublist in ligands.values() for item in sublist]
                
    io=PDBIO()
    io.set_structure(structure)
    io.save(filename+'.pdb', LigandSelect(), preserve_atom_numbering=False)
```

my code `main.py` :

```
from Bio import PDB

from Bio.PDB import PDBIO


import active_site as SV


parser = PDB.PDBParser(PERMISSIVE=1, QUIET=1)

structure: PDB.Structure.Structure = parser.get_structure("prova", "2r09.pdb")

ligand = SV.get_ligand_by_name('4IP', structure[0])

print('ligand -> ', ligand, type(ligand))

SV.save_ligand(structure[0], 'ligand')
```

I can load your PDB files and save both the ligands present in the structure

(same ligand for two different chains: A,B ; don't know if protein is monomer or dimer (i.e. monomer but dimeric in AU, actual dimer))

my results as `ligand.pdb` is:

```
HETATM    1  C1  4IP A 405      80.967  85.113  26.680  1.00 22.42           C  
HETATM    2  O1  4IP A 405      82.327  85.039  27.129  1.00 23.40           O  
HETATM    3  C2  4IP A 405      80.917  85.791  25.309  1.00 22.60           C  
HETATM    4  O2  4IP A 405      81.463  87.121  25.385  1.00 20.92           O  
HETATM    5  C3  4IP A 405      79.465  85.823  24.827  1.00 20.89           C  
HETATM    6  O3  4IP A 405      79.392  86.282  23.475  1.00 20.17           O  
HETATM    7  C4  4IP A 405      78.585  86.660  25.757  1.00 20.60           C  
HETATM    8  O4  4IP A 405      77.224  86.534  25.358  1.00 20.32           O  
HETATM    9  C5  4IP A 405      78.675  86.137  27.199  1.00 21.70           C  
HETATM   10  O5  4IP A 405      77.999  87.108  28.007  1.00 20.84           O  
HETATM   11  C6  4IP A 405      80.116  85.898  27.686  1.00 21.33           C  
HETATM   12  O6  4IP A 405      80.130  85.209  28.962  1.00 21.36           O  
HETATM   13  P1  4IP A 405      83.280  83.762  26.840  1.00 25.39           P  
HETATM   14  O1P 4IP A 405      84.620  84.387  27.067  1.00 24.93           O  
HETATM   15  O2P 4IP A 405      83.011  83.316  25.424  1.00 24.90           O  
HETATM   16  O3P 4IP A 405      82.883  82.738  27.868  1.00 26.91           O  
HETATM   17  P3  4IP A 405      78.855  85.297  22.324  1.00 20.21           P  
HETATM   18  O4P 4IP A 405      77.428  84.990  22.747  1.00 20.15           O  
HETATM   19  O5P 4IP A 405      79.754  84.074  22.330  1.00 21.26           O  
HETATM   20  O6P 4IP A 405      78.942  86.136  21.074  1.00 19.72           O  
HETATM   21  P4  4IP A 405      76.408  87.690  24.600  1.00 19.61           P  
HETATM   22  O7P 4IP A 405      77.277  88.918  24.665  1.00 19.52           O  
HETATM   23  O8P 4IP A 405      75.127  87.775  25.380  1.00 19.15           O  
HETATM   24  O9P 4IP A 405      76.215  87.157  23.199  1.00 19.73           O  
HETATM   25  P5  4IP A 405      77.266  86.724  29.383  1.00 21.18           P  
HETATM   26  OPF 4IP A 405      76.447  85.480  29.103  1.00 19.82           O  
HETATM   27  OPG 4IP A 405      76.396  87.922  29.662  1.00 21.85           O  
HETATM   28  OPH 4IP A 405      78.385  86.527  30.363  1.00 20.70           O  
TER      29      4IP A 405                                                       
HETATM   29  C1  4IP B 400      19.832  75.384  -3.106  1.00 26.91           C  
HETATM   30  O1  4IP B 400      18.852  74.503  -3.643  1.00 28.03           O  
HETATM   31  C2  4IP B 400      19.809  75.360  -1.573  1.00 25.72           C  
HETATM   32  O2  4IP B 400      18.531  75.764  -1.075  1.00 26.15           O  
HETATM   33  C3  4IP B 400      20.886  76.313  -1.046  1.00 25.51           C  
HETATM   34  O3  4IP B 400      20.949  76.259   0.388  1.00 24.29           O  
HETATM   35  C4  4IP B 400      20.660  77.747  -1.535  1.00 24.17           C  
HETATM   36  O4  4IP B 400      21.786  78.546  -1.164  1.00 23.22           O  
HETATM   37  C5  4IP B 400      20.563  77.819  -3.060  1.00 26.06           C  
HETATM   38  O5  4IP B 400      20.179  79.156  -3.403  1.00 24.79           O  
HETATM   39  C6  4IP B 400      19.613  76.789  -3.678  1.00 26.21           C  
HETATM   40  O6  4IP B 400      19.845  76.713  -5.095  1.00 26.93           O  
HETATM   41  P1  4IP B 400      19.148  72.969  -4.040  1.00 30.18           P  
HETATM   42  O1P 4IP B 400      17.769  72.379  -3.959  1.00 29.62           O  
HETATM   43  O2P 4IP B 400      19.703  72.997  -5.442  1.00 32.15           O  
HETATM   44  O3P 4IP B 400      20.131  72.484  -3.004  1.00 30.58           O  
HETATM   45  P3  4IP B 400      22.293  75.724   1.102  1.00 25.03           P  
HETATM   46  O4P 4IP B 400      23.378  76.683   0.677  1.00 23.91           O  
HETATM   47  O5P 4IP B 400      22.477  74.324   0.571  1.00 24.81           O  
HETATM   48  O6P 4IP B 400      21.967  75.846   2.579  1.00 23.92           O  
HETATM   49  P4  4IP B 400      21.769  79.638   0.027  1.00 24.76           P  
HETATM   50  O7P 4IP B 400      20.352  79.738   0.497  1.00 22.44           O  
HETATM   51  O8P 4IP B 400      22.374  80.892  -0.565  1.00 23.32           O  
HETATM   52  O9P 4IP B 400      22.674  79.045   1.083  1.00 24.83           O  
HETATM   53  P5  4IP B 400      20.543  79.836  -4.819  1.00 27.59           P  
HETATM   54  OPF 4IP B 400      22.002  79.494  -5.029  1.00 26.64           O  
HETATM   55  OPG 4IP B 400      20.334  81.296  -4.538  1.00 26.24           O  
HETATM   56  OPH 4IP B 400      19.586  79.196  -5.799  1.00 25.90           O  
TER      57      4IP B 400                                                       
END
```

the coordinates look similar to original pdb:

```
HETATM 5636  C1  4IP A 405      80.967  85.113  26.680  1.00 22.42           C  
HETATM 5637  O1  4IP A 405      82.327  85.039  27.129  1.00 23.40           O  
HETATM 5638  C2  4IP A 405      80.917  85.791  25.309  1.00 22.60           C
```

.....

```
HETATM 5706  C1  4IP B 400      19.832  75.384  -3.106  1.00 26.91           C  
HETATM 5707  O1  4IP B 400      18.852  74.503  -3.643  1.00 28.03           O  
HETATM 5708  C2  4IP B 400      19.809  75.360  -1.573  1.00 25.72           C  
HETATM 5709  O2  4IP B 400      18.531  75.764  -1.075  1.00 26.15           O
```

check it out, to see if I didn't make any mistake. Can't you upgrade to 1.79 from  1.78 ?

Answer (score 0):

copying from [How to save each ligand from a PDB file separately with Bio.PDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61390035/how-to-save-each-ligand-from-a-pdb-file-separately-with-bio-pdb) approach:

```
from Bio import PDB

from Bio.PDB import PDBIO, Select



class ResidueSelect(Select):
    def __init__(self, chain, residue):
        self.chain = chain
        self.residue = residue

    def accept_chain(self, chain):
            return chain.id == self.chain.id

            
    def accept_residue(self, residue):
            """ Recognition of heteroatoms - Remove water molecules """
            return residue == self.residue



def extract_ligands(file, ligand):
    
    parser = PDB.PDBParser(PERMISSIVE=1, QUIET=1)

    structure: PDB.Structure.Structure = parser.get_structure(file.split('.')[-1], file)
    
    print('ooooooo : ' ,file.split('.')[0])

    
    io = PDBIO()
    io.set_structure(structure)
    
    i=1
    for model in structure:
        for chain in model:
            for residue in chain:
                if residue.get_resname() == ligand:
    
                    print(f"saving {chain} {residue}")
                    io.save(f"lig_{file.split('.')[0]}_{i}.pdb", ResidueSelect(chain, residue))
                    i += 1


extract_ligands("2r09.pdb", '4IP')
```

outputs:

`lig_2r09_1` :

```
HETATM    1  C1  4IP A 405      80.967  85.113  26.680  1.00 22.42           C  
HETATM    2  O1  4IP A 405      82.327  85.039  27.129  1.00 23.40           O  
HETATM    3  C2  4IP A 405      80.917  85.791  25.309  1.00 22.60           C  
HETATM    4  O2  4IP A 405      81.463  87.121  25.385  1.00 20.92           O  
HETATM    5  C3  4IP A 405      79.465  85.823  24.827  1.00 20.89           C  
........................
```

`lig_2r09_2` :

```
HETATM    1  C1  4IP B 400      19.832  75.384  -3.106  1.00 26.91           C  
HETATM    2  O1  4IP B 400      18.852  74.503  -3.643  1.00 28.03           O  
HETATM    3  C2  4IP B 400      19.809  75.360  -1.573  1.00 25.72           C  
HETATM    4  O2  4IP B 400      18.531  75.764  -1.075  1.00 26.15           O  
...................
```

Again using >Biopython 1.78 seems to get right coords